# Is there a way to limit the number of pages the Navigation Stack can maintain in a Flutter App?

Tags: dart, flutter

In my Flutter App I notice my Navigation Stack keeps growing. Is there a way to limit the number of pages that can be in memory in the Navigation Stack (say maximum of 4 pages) ?

Also is it possible to minimise / close the Flutter App after a certain number of "Back" Button triggers have been made by the user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any setting that allows you to set this up. Hence, I am going to propose a method of handling it yourself.

The following two variables are *top-level*, i.e. you can place them anywhere outside of a class. Alternatively, you could use an [`InheritedWidget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) to store the data, but I will not do that for simplicity.

```
int openedRoutes = 1, routePops = 0;
```

There are two approaches to catching route pops. You can either only catch those that originate from the system, e.g. the Android back button or also catch your `Navigator` pop calls. All manual ones you want to record will have to be performed using `Navigator.maybePop` instead of `Navigator.pop`.

Now, you just need to wrap all your pages in the following widget that makes use of [`WillPopScope`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) to track `routePops`:

```
class TrackPops extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  TrackPops({Key key, @required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => 
      WillPopScope(child: child, onWillPop: () async {
            if (routePops++ >= backButtonLimit) /// [backButtonLimit] defined below
              SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
            openedRoutes--;
            return true;
          });
}
```

Now, you can just work with the two variables every time you push routes. As mentioned before, an `InheritedWidget` would be the idiomatic path to take, which you would just retrieve using [`BuildContext.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/inheritFromWidgetOfExactType.html).

Example implementation where you have a route limit of `4` and back button presses of `2`:

```
const int routeLimit = 4, backButtonLimit = 2;

void pushRoute(BuildContext context, Route route) {
  if (openedRoutes >= routeLimit) return;
  Navigator.of(context).push(route);
  openedRoutes++;
  routePops = 0;
}
```

Comment: Ya this a good way of doing it. But it would be nice if flutter has a method to handle this.